# sample mean or population mean for Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test

Tags: r, statistics, mean

Should the population mean be used or the sample mean to test for Wilcoxon Signed Rank test

I am testing with wilcoxon signed rank test for a survey sample of 400 responded. Should I use the population mean or the sample mean for the calculation of wilcoxon signed rank test?

```
wilcox.test(GroupA, mu = x, conf.level=0.95)
```

For instance if 400 people complete the survey this is the population and also the sample I will be using so what mean should I use in `mu = x` in the above script?

Comment: `mu` should be the measure of central tendency for population, and usually median is used. You should provide the hypothesized value of `mu` here.

Comment: Thanks Yarnabrina. One more question if you do not mind, My Statistic lecturer told me to use Wilcoxon signed rank test in order to analyse survey data. 
Everywhere i searched i understood that Wilcoxon signed rank test is used to compare two sample \ survey at different time interval. However I only have one survey of ordinal data and I do not understand why i should use Wilcoxon Signed test since i do not have another sample to compare with. 
The lecturer also told me to use alternative = "great" why is this?

Comment: There are two tests: Wilcoxxon Signed Rank Test and Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test. The second one is for comparing medians for two populations (equivalent to Mann Whitney U Test), and another is for comparing median for one population with a pre-specified value (usually location change is done to make it `0`). Probably, you're looking for this test. Though if your data is ordinal in the sense that non-numeric observation with inherent ordering, then I don't know how to use it.

Comment: OK thank a million. I think the Signed rank test is correct and the data must be converted in numerical value. For instance 1 lowest disagreement (Highly disagree)and 6 highest agreement (Highly agree). The you can use Singed rank test. What do you mean by usually location change is done to make it 0?

Comment: If you're checking median of `X` to be `k`, it is equivalent to checking median of `X - k` is `0`. But please checcking before converting ordinal categories to numbers, as the categories are not really "equispaced".

Comment: I think can be done but you need to avoid neutral answers. For instance the scale can not be Very unhappy, unhappy, OK, happy, very happy but must be on a 6 level scale Very unhappy, unhappy,slightly unhappy, slightly happy, happy, very happy..thanks a million !!